# How to diagnose whether a customer's ISP is throttling access to my website?

Tags: networking, website, isp, performance, throttling

We host a website that servers up mostly static files, such as html and flash SWF files. The server is hosted in Auckland, New Zealand.

Our customers are mainly secondary/high-schools.  In general, most customers can access our website at perfectly acceptable speeds.

For some customers in a certain region of Australia, we are receiving reports of extremely slow loading times for our website.

After talking to a couple of system administrators at the schools, it *sounds* like the common thread is that these schools share the same ISP.  From what I can gather, the ISP is throttling the traffic coming from our website.

What methods and tools can I use to determine if this is *in fact* the cause?

Comment: The first tool I would try, is to ask your customers, to ask their supplier if they are throttling/shaping their bandwidth.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to establish this *in fact* would be for the ISP to confirm it.  If you are providing a legitimate service to one of those schools, and have a good relationship with a sys admin at the school, then you could do worse than ask one of them to contact their ISP and check.  Why would they be throttling your service?

You could run your own [Glasnost test server](http://broadband.mpi-sws.org/transparency/code.html) and have some someone at an affected site run tests, and compare against a site served by a different ISP.

Comment: `Why would they be throttling your service?` - Because most Australian ISPs are rediculous, sadly. It would not be the craziest thing they've ever done.